# How to continious scroll bottomModelSheet after child ListView completes the scroll in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, scroll

I have the `showModalBottomSheet` widget which I am calling when the user clicks on a button and it has `listView` as a child widget.

with this, I am able to scroll through the bottom model sheet,

But how to continuously scroll the bottom model sheet down after the listview has completed scrolling down?

Currently, the bottom model sheet does not go down just the `ListView` indicates the completion of scroll.

[image]

instead of scroll complete feedback, I want to scroll down the `BottomModelSheet` when `ListView` done scrolling.
Is there any way to achieve this with `showModalBottomSheet'?

Answer (score 1):

```
  class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Press Me'),
              onPressed: () async => await showModalBottomSheet(
                  // isScrollControlled: true,
                  context: context,
                  builder: (ctx) => ListViewWidget()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListViewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListViewWidgetState createState() => _ListViewWidgetState();
}

class _ListViewWidgetState extends State<ListViewWidget> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  ScrollPhysics _scrollPhysics;

  void _scrollListener() async {
    if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
        _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent) {
      setState(() {
        _scrollPhysics = NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);
    _scrollPhysics = AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: kStates.length,
      controller: _scrollController,
      physics: _scrollPhysics,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) => GestureDetector(
        child: Text(
          kStates[index],
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `BottomBodelSheet` should start to dismiss when the scroll of the child `ListView` reaches the end (I mean when there is no scroll left to scroll down), currently, there is little red Color overflow indication, when the scroll ends, want to continue to scroll down the entire bottomModelsheet when scroll is completed. Instead, of showing the overflow indication.

Comment: Now, as you can see the `BottomModelSheet` has the `ListView` as a child,  sheet takes the full screen, now, as you can see above how to you dismiss the sheet. Because without pressing the back button the bottom model sheet cannot be dismissed, right?. Because scrolling is stuck at the 'ListView'.

Comment: I want the `BottomModelSheet` to be more like the `DraggableScrollableSheet'` but you cannot show the `DraggableScrollableSheet` when the user click, hence we are using `showBottomModelSheet`, hope you got it now.

Comment: do you want it to take up the whole screen usually when I use ```bottomModelSheet``` I don't have it take up the entire screen that way the user can just tap on an area above the ```bottomModelSheet``` to close it

Comment: ya, that is, there, I will also won't cover the entire screen, but this is my requirement.

Comment: okay give me a couple minutes ill see what I can come up with

Comment: I put some code above check it out tell me what you think

Comment: it is, almost ok, but it is supposed to dissmissed when it is scrolled all the way down

Comment: when is it being dismissed on yours

Comment: no, when the scroll bar is reached topmost point ie:- there is no more content at the top, then when I scroll further the ModelSheet should continuously start to dismiss. like scrollableDraggableSheet.

Comment: currently, you are, abruptly dismissing the sheet when the scroll bar reached the bottom ie:- there is no content at the bottom. You got it completely opposite of what was required

Comment: using scroll is very confusing, I am using the word "Scroll Bar", anyway scroll moves opposite to the "Scroll bar"

Comment: just put lot of scroll content and see for your self.

Comment: Okay check out the new code see if I got any closer to what you wanted l'll explain cause I was way over thinking the problem so ```botttomModelSheet``` already has the functionality you want but by adding a ```listView```  it overrides that dismiss functionality you want so you just have to detect when you are at the top of you list and then make it not scrollable. I hope this at least get you closer.

Comment: it works one time, try to scroll the list multiple time, it gets stuck, then there is no way to scroll, the only thing you can do is to continue to dismiss the sheet and open it again, try many  items in the list

Comment: Anyway, nice try, I think this is not possible without adding a gesture detector on the top of the sheet and handle stroll yourself,

Comment: I tried Gesture detector i wanted to do it that way if you can get it to work that way go for it. It Didn't work at all for me when I added it